# How I change this text from backend page?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make a scrolling text box in a page "front-end page" read from text file "msg.txt"

```
<div class="scroll-slow">
  <?php echo file_get_contents('../msg.txt'); ?>
</div>
```

I added this code to add textbox and save button in my backend:

```
<html> 
  <head> 
      <title></title> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
   <form action="msg.txt" method="POST"> 
     <input name="field1" type="text" /> 
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"> 
    </form> 
   </body> 
  </html>

<?php 
 if(isset($_POST['field1'])) {
     $data = $_POST['field1'] . "\n"; 
     $ret = file_put_contents('../msg.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX); 
     if($ret === false) { 
        die('There was an error writing this file'); 
     } else { 
        echo "$ret bytes written to file"; 
     } 
   } else { 
    die('no post data to process'); 
   }?>
```

Also I included txt file called "msg.txt" in my root, to make the save button save the text into the file then the scrolling msg box will read the file

**My problem is:**

- The scrolling textbox doesn't read from the file
- The save button doesn't save into the file it's just open the file!

**What I'm doing wrong?**
I'm sorry I know it's a mess, but I'm trying to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make `action` tag blank to execute the `PHP` code which is inside if statement

Change

```
action="msg.txt"
```

to

```
action=""
```

If you are doing coding on `PH`, you should use php file in `action` tag, you can not perform any action on `txt` file.

To append the text every time to existing file use

```
$txt = "This is text";
$myfile = file_put_contents('text_file.txt', $txt.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Comment: Okay I did like what you have said, now it saves to the file, but the text is added to the file not updated. so every-time I save the text will be added next the the old one

Comment: @Someone do you want to append the field value every time when form is submitted ?

Answer (score 1):

Here you can use jquery and ajax for get activ value of text

```
$.ajax({
    url: "backendFile.php",
    type: "post",
    data: {
        text: $("input[name='field1']").val()
    },
    success: (e) => {
        $(".scroll-slow").html(e)
    }
}
```

Your backendFile.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['field1'])) {
        $data = $_POST['field1'] . "\n";
        $ret = file_put_contents('../msg.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        if($ret === false) {
            die('There was an error writing this file');
        } else {
            echo "$ret bytes written to file\n".file_get_contents("../msg.txt");
        }
    } else {
        die('no post data to process');
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are submitting the form data to a text file, text files won't be able to handle form data.

You need to send data to php file, in your case just removing the action from form tag would work.